# Using Javascript with Asp.net for ListBox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, client-side

I want to use ClientSide Javascript for listbox, it should take values from database table when the page is loaded first time OR load the specific table in javascript, 
Right Now, all the values are coming from database, if I select "StandardM1(CA)"

[image: UI With Dropdown Open]

it brings all the values from "food_menu" table.

[image: UI After Dropdown Option Selected]

I want to do the the same thing with client-side javascript in order to save time and server requests, so that the application runs faster.
Can some one please guide me?

Answer (score -3):

Faheem use array in it and try to do the coding right on the save button. its the save button that is creating problems

Comment: I think you are the inverter of .NET, thanks a lot for your suggestions, but my question was not what you answered :D